# High fan speed after suspend only on AC [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management, battery, fan

I noticed that after suspend, if my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T470s)  is on AC, the fan kicks in at 100%. If I resume suspend without AC, it works just fine. I noticed this on cold boot Ubuntu 16.04 (possibly with powertop calibrated).

```
hmerzic@home:~$ uname -a
Linux home 4.10.0-32-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After suspend on AC

```
hmerzic@home:~$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan 
status:     enabled
speed:      4638
level:      auto
```

After suspend on battery

```
hmerzic@home:~$ cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan 
status:     enabled
speed:      0
level:      auto
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I have the same problem with a Lenovo 5th generation Carbon X1 running 16.04. I hadn't noticed that it was related to being on AC. I can't answer your question but can confirm that this is not solely about the T470s.

Comment: I had the same issue with my T470s, with the power cable connected and in the docking station. Following [this discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1480844), I found that there is a [BIOS update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/uy/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-T-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-T470S/downloads/DS120418), which fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I will definitely check that out. I did do a similar thing when I noticed the issue, but that was already a long time ago. I guess it's time for another BIOS update! :)

Comment: Thinkpad t460s: UEFI BIOS 1.44 (N1CET76W), ECP 1.14 (N1CHT32W), Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel 4.19.60 => seems fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, but I would like to know why this issue was there in the first place. I tried toggling all options tuned by powertop until I noticed that the issue is gone. The option that was causing the problem was this one:

```
Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
```

When the state is Good the following option is set (this causes the problem)

```
echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.6/power/control';
```

and when it is Bad it is

```
echo 'on' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.6/power/control';
```

Anyone knows why this causes the problem?

**UPDATE:** As per the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948025/high-fan-speed-after-suspend-only-on-ac-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1564746_948025) posted by Daniel Nyga, the official BIOS update 1.20 addresses the fan issue. After following [this guide](https://workaround.org/article/updating-the-bios-on-lenovo-laptops-from-linux-using-a-usb-flash-stick/), the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my X1 carbon 4th generation (model 20fc): The cpu fan was stuck at 100% and the cpu sensor (`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`) was stuck at 48 degrees.

See [this kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=191181) and [this duplicate](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196129). It *seems* to be fixed from Kernel 4.12 or 4.13 onwards, but not for everyone.

What hamzam suggested *sometimes* worked:

```
sudo sh -c "echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.6/power/control"
```

In the end what solved the issue for me was trying an *older* bios versions from lenovo:

1. Google for "bios update bootable" and your model number, `X1 20fc` in my case
2. try older versions, but not too old. I just did a "binary search" until I found a version which worked (`n1fur22w` in my case)

Flash it unto usb (taken from [this guide](https://workaround.org/article/updating-the-bios-on-lenovo-laptops-from-linux-using-a-usb-flash-stick/), also linked in hamzams answer):

```
geteltorito -o bios.img n1fur22w.iso
sudo dd if=bios.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M
sudo dd if=bios.img of=/dev/sda bs=1M
```

Yes, I needed to flash it twice.. then, reboot, press F12 and boot from USB. I needed to disable fastboot to boot from USB and also needed to enable BIOS downgrade at some point.

What was also not clear to me: a successful downgrade progress bar looks like this (you'll recognize it when you see it):

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
.......................
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using Ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenovo ThinkPad T470s.
Updating the BIOS seems to have fixed the issue.